# Finding the matrix relative to the bases

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The question is in blue ink and my answer is in pencil, my problem is that I don't know if I am fully answering the question or if I am even answering it correctly. Any help would be appreciated. Book is Linear Algebra the gateway to mathematics by messer the problems are from section 6.3 review exercises

[image]

[image: r al]

Comment: These look OK except for the spurious $\implies$ in both.

Comment: In the future, please take the time to enter key parts of your question (in this case, pretty much the entire question!) as text instead of pasting pictures of them. Use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format mathematical expressions. Your question is completely incomprehensible without those images, and so inaccessible to people who depend on screen readers. Moreover, images are neither searchable nor show up in summaries.