# Compute the matrix $P^{-1}AP$ of $T$ relative to $B'$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm confused about part b, am I just computing the matrix for changing from B to B^1 now?

[image: -1]

Comment: What exactly is it that you’re confused about? Perform the indicated multiplication.

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment [to a previous question of yours](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3657832/265466), please take the time to enter your questions as text instead of pasting pictures of them. This one is completely incomprehensible without that image, which makes it inaccessible to people who depend on screen readers, not searchable, &c. You’re asking others to spend their time to help you; it’s only fair that you take some time of your own to meet the standards of this site. See [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10992/265466) in particular w/r formatting a question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to find $P$ which is the change of basis matrix and then basically multiply the three matrices